# difficulty working with subList when using a list of lists

Tags: java, list

```
public List<List<Integer>> splitList(
        List<Integer> values) {


    List<List<Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    //Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> to List<List<Integer>>

    while (values.size() > numValuesInClause) {
        List<Integer> sublist = values.subList(0,numValuesInClause);
        List<Integer> values2 = values.subList(numValuesInClause, values.size());   
        values = values2; 

        newList.add( sublist);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

I want to pass in a list of integers, and split it out in to multiple lists of less that size `numValuesInClause`.

I'm having difficulty with this code, with various conversions/casting between `ArrayList<Integer>` and `List<Integer>`

For example `List.subList(x,y)` returns a `List<E>`

What's the best way to work here?

The current code shown here is what makes the most sense to me, but has the compilation error shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
List<List<Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

instead of:

```
List<List<Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

The reason for this, is that you are instantiating a concrete `ArrayList` of a *generic* element `List<Integer>>`